# Customizing the shell prompt causes some quirks

Tags: terminal, bash, command-line

I have customized the shell prompt with the following code in my `~/.bash_profile`, but there is one quirk left I can't seem to fix:

```
export PS1="\u:\[\e[32;1;32m\W\e[m\] \$ "
```

(code is [also on github](https://gist.github.com/1319600))

This works well, including for long commands. But if I page through the command history with the arrow keys, the prompt will sometimes get a bit "weird". Sometimes it will include a partial command in the prompt or other times the space after the `$` will be disappear. Is there something missing from the code above that I should tweak?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't close the brackets for the first escape, and add the escape for the second

```
export PS1="\u:\[\e[32;1;32m\]\W\[\e[m\] \$ "
#---------------------------^^--^^
```

Comment: Thank you! Was going cross-eyed trying to get it all to work. :)